# Excelize freeze rows generates a file with errors

Tags: go, excelize, 360entsecgroup-skylar-excelize

I am trying to freeze the top row and the first two columns of the sheet.

```
xlsx.SetPanes(sheetName, `{"freeze":true,"x_split":2,"y_split":1,"top_left_cell":"A1","active_pane":"topLeft","panes":[{"sqref":"A1:B1","pane":"topLeft"},{"sqref":"C1:XFD1", "pane":"topRight"},{"sqref":"A2:B2", "pane":"bottomLeft"},{"sqref":"C3:XFD3", "pane":"bottomRight"}]}`)
```

If I open the file in excel I get the below alert and after I try to recover the recovery log shows nothing removed:

Alert:

```
We found a problem with some content in ’test.xlsx’. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.
```

Recovery log:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
      <recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
         <logFileName>Repair Result to test3.xml</logFileName>
         <summary>Errors were detected in file ’/test.xlsx’</summary>
         <repairedRecords summary="Following is a list of repairs:">
             <repairedRecord>Repaired Records: View from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</repairedRecord>
         </repairedRecords>
      </recoveryLog>
```

This is not a problem with the data as the file works fine if I remove the setPanes method. What am I doing wrong?

Also note that if I open the file with google sheets its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out in the end

```
xlsx.SetPanes(sheetName, `{"freeze":true,"x_split":2,"y_split":1,"top_left_cell":"C2","active_pane":"bottomRight","panes":[{"pane":"topLeft"},{"pane":"topRight"},{"pane":"bottomLeft"},{"active_cell":"C2", "sqref":"C2", "pane":"bottomRight"}]}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Example. Setting Freeze in the first column and the first three rows:

```
xlsx.SetPanes(sheet, `
    {
        "freeze":true,
        "x_split":1,
        "y_split":3,
        "top_left_cell":"B4",
        "active_pane":"bottomRight",
        "panes":[
            {"pane":"topLeft"},
            {"pane":"topRight"},
            {"pane":"bottomLeft"},
            {"active_cell":"B4", "sqref":"B4", "pane":"bottomRight"}
            ]
    }
`)
```

The key seems to determine what is your `x_split`,`y_split` value and `sqref` location. A bit of struggle but props to the author for figuring out.